# String to Float in Python 3.10. Which format of the string?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

i want to convert a string into a float with Python 3.10.

The problem is the format of the string. For example:

```
"  3.841-11"
```

which stands for 3.841e-011.

I tried the classical

```
float("  3.841-11")
```

but this gives an error.

Just to change this one string is no solution, because i want to read a bigger file like this:

```
$$
$$  GRID Data
$$

GRID           1        -44.0332667.9   -2.55271
GRID           2        -39.1406667.9   -2.26907
GRID           3        -34.2481667.9   -1.98544
GRID           4        -29.3555667.9   -1.70181
GRID           5        -24.4629667.9   -1.41817
GRID           6        -19.5703667.9   -1.13454
GRID           7        -14.6777667.9   -.850903
GRID           8        -9.78516667.9   -.567269
GRID           9        -4.89258667.9   -.283634
GRID          10        3.055-13667.9   3.841-11
GRID          11        4.892579667.9   .2836343
```

This is my code:

```py
    def read_fem(location):  
        mesh = open(location, 'r').read().splitlines()
    
        point = []
    
        for i in range(1, len(mesh)):
            if '$' not in mesh[i]:
    
                if 'GRID' in mesh[i]:
                    number = int(mesh[i][8:16])
                    x = float(mesh[i][24:32])
                    y = float(mesh[i][32:40])
                    z = float(mesh[i][40:48])
    
                    point.append([number, x, y, z])
```

Grateful for every answer.

Comment: What about the trailing `667.9` in all numbers of the 3rd column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program will:

- assume the file is named: `grid_data.txt`
- look for hyphens surrounded by numbers eg. `3.841-11` and convert to `3.841e-11`
- **ignore** hyphens at the beginning of numbers eg. `-44.0332`

The `fix_float()` function is allowing the conversion to happen.

- The regex in use is `\d(-)\d`

#### Code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\d(-)\d')

def fix_float(m):
    val = m.group(0).replace('-','e-')
    return val

def read_fem(location):  
    mesh = open(location, 'r').read().splitlines()
    point = []

    for m in mesh:
        if '$' not in m:
            if 'GRID' in m:
                number = int(m[8:16])
                x = float(pattern.sub(fix_float, m[24:32]))
                y = float(pattern.sub(fix_float, m[32:40]))
                z = float(pattern.sub(fix_float, m[40:48]))

                point.append([number, x, y, z])
    return point


# Extract the data from the file                
data = read_fem('grid_data.txt')

# Display the data
for point in data:
    print(point)
```

#### Output:

```
[1, -44.0332, 667.9, -2.55271]
[2, -39.1406, 667.9, -2.26907]
[3, -34.2481, 667.9, -1.98544]
[4, -29.3555, 667.9, -1.70181]
[5, -24.4629, 667.9, -1.41817]
[6, -19.5703, 667.9, -1.13454]
[7, -14.6777, 667.9, -0.850903]
[8, -9.78516, 667.9, -0.567269]
[9, -4.89258, 667.9, -0.283634]
[10, 3.055e-13, 667.9, 3.841e-11]
[11, 4.892579, 667.9, 0.2836343]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)

IMO, it would be better not to parse your file manually, but rather to use a library. [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) is ideal for this. Start by reading your file with [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html), then `replace` the `-` (or `+`) preceded by a digit by the correct exponent form before converting to float:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', sep='\s+', colspecs=[(8,16),(24,32),(32,40),(40,48)])

# fix the incorrect numbers
# and convert to float
data.update(data.select_dtypes(exclude='number')
                .apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(r'(?<=\d)(?=[-+])', 'e', regex=True)
                                  .astype(float))
            )

# convert to list
out = data.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[1, -44.0332, 667.9, -2.55271],
 [2, -39.1406, 667.9, -2.26907],
 [3, -34.2481, 667.9, -1.98544],
 [4, -29.3555, 667.9, -1.70181],
 [5, -24.4629, 667.9, -1.41817],
 [6, -19.5703, 667.9, -1.13454],
 [7, -14.6777, 667.9, -0.850903],
 [8, -9.78516, 667.9, -0.567269],
 [9, -4.89258, 667.9, -0.283634],
 [10, 3.055e-13, 667.9, 3.841e-11],
 [11, 4.892579, 667.9, 0.2836343]]
```

#### older answer

Replace `-` with `e-` before converting to `float`:

```
s = '3.841-11'

out = float(s.replace('-', 'e-'))
```

Output: `3.841e-11`

A more generic approach if you can have `e+` as well could be to use a regex:

```
import re

s = '3.841+4'

out = float(re.sub(r'(?=[-+])', 'e', s))
```

Output: `38410.0`

##### short program to fix your file

This reads `data.txt` and outputs the fixed floats in `data_clean.txt`.

```
import re
with open('data.txt') as f, open('data_clean.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[-+])', 'e', f.read()))
```

I also see that you have numbers like `3.055-13667.9`, which would be invalid as the exponent must be an integer. You can also fix those:

```
import re
with open('data.txt') as f, open('data_clean.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)([-+])(\d+.\d?)', lambda m: f'e{m.group(1)}{int(float(m.group(2)))}', f.read()))
```

Fixed file:

```
$$
$$  GRID Data
$$

GRID           1        -44.0332667.9   -2.55271
GRID           2        -39.1406667.9   -2.26907
GRID           3        -34.2481667.9   -1.98544
GRID           4        -29.3555667.9   -1.70181
GRID           5        -24.4629667.9   -1.41817
GRID           6        -19.5703667.9   -1.13454
GRID           7        -14.6777667.9   -.850903
GRID           8        -9.78516667.9   -.567269
GRID           9        -4.89258667.9   -.283634
GRID          10        3.055e-13667   3.841e-11
GRID          11        4.892579667.9   .2836343
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I revised my question. I want to read a bigger file so i think i cant solve it like this.

Comment: @RaHeSch the size of the file doesn't matter, you can apply this to every value or line from the file one by one.

Comment: The regular expression could be more robust if it forced a digit before the +/-.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried it but this line puts the e now before every '-' . 

For example '  -2.55271' -> '  e-2.55271'

Comment: @RaHeSch you should consider using csv/pandas to read your file, then you can apply a transformation to convert to floats